# Proof for linearly independent eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Given the eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ of the transformation $f$, the eigenvectors correspondent the them are respectively $v$ and $w$. Prove that $v$ is L.I with $w$.

My proof:

Let's assume that $v$ and $w$ are L.D, hence:
$$
v = c\cdot w
$$

It's indeed true that:
$$
f(v) = \lambda_1v\\
f(w) = \lambda_2w
$$

Now applying what we've assumed:
$$
f(v) = f(c\cdot w)\\
f(c\cdot w) = c \cdot f(w) = c \lambda_2w\\
\lambda_1 v = c \lambda_2w\\
\text{applying again our assumption to v}\\
c \lambda_1  w = c\lambda_2 w\\
\lambda_1  w = \lambda_2 w
$$
What we've concluded it's impossible, because $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$, hence, our vectors can't be L.D, so they are L.I.

Comment: This looks just fine...perhaps just to remark that *it must be* $\;c\neq0\;$ (why?) +1

Comment: your approach is correct

Comment: @DonAntonio $c\neq 0$ because of $v = c\cdot w$. if $c=0$ that assumptions is not correct.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Your answer on a question that I did early in this afternoon was perfect my friend. I was nervous and couldn't get to understand it in that moment... Now I get it. Thank you for that!

Comment: @BrunoReis In fact, I was thinking more on the direction that $\;c=0\implies v=cw=0\;$ , but eigenvectors are different from zero *by definition* .

Comment: eigenvectors and eigenvalues are diferrent from zero by definition right mate? because we can't assign any eigenvector to a zero eigenvalue...